# Mouseflow session id Adobe Analytics

Tags: adobe-analytics

Can someone help me how to implement mouseflow session-id and how I suppose to assign to an evar using Adobe Launch?

https://help.mouseflow.com/en/articles/4306147-exporting-mouseflow-data-to-third-party-tools

Help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Balakrishna

Comment: needs detail or clarity

Comment: Hi Babak, Thanks for your quick response. I want to track the mouseflow session id to Adobe Analytics variable evar.